# Good UI Design: How to handle empty ListView?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, listview

My app connects to the net and populates a ListView. Sometimes nothing will be returned. What is the best way to notify the user the list is empty?

Some of my own suggestions:

- Show "No Results" in the first ListItem
- Show a new view that says "No Results"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ListView allows you to have an alternative view shown when it is empty:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)

In fact, if you use a ListActivity whose layout has a view with android:id="@android:id/empty", it will automatically hook this up for you.

So typically you could put the ListView and your empty view in a FrameLayout, and have the empty view have some nice text centered in its area telling the user there is nothing to show.

Answer (score 3):

> Show a new view that says "No Results"

This is the correct option. Do not confuse your user by presenting an info message as a list item. They are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

I choose "Show "*No Results" in the first ListItem*".

Because users could connect the "*No Results*" to the *ListItem* directly, while new view leads users to have to accept new thing.